# как через ng-repeat вывести правильно массивы

Tags: angularjs

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "category": "Ванные комнаты",
    "example": [
      {
        "source": "img/design/gallery/bathRoom",
        "format": ".jpg"
      },
      {
        "source": "img/design/gallery/bathRoom",
        "format": ".jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Гостиная комнаты",
    "example": [
      {
        "source": "img/design/gallery/livingRoom",
        "format": ".jpg"
      },
      {
        "source": "img/design/gallery/livingRoom",
        "format": ".jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Нужно вывести след образом:**

**HTML**

```
   <div>
       <a href="#">Ванные комнаты</a>
       <a href="#">Гостиная комнаты</a>
    </div>

    <ul>
       <li>
          <p>Путь: img/design/gallery/bathRoom</p>
          <p>Формат: .jpg</p>
       </li>
       <li>
          <p>Путь: img/design/gallery/bathRoom</p>
          <p>Формат: .jpg</p>
       </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li>
          <p>Путь: img/design/gallery/livingRoom</p>
          <p>Формат: .jpg</p>
       </li>
       <li>
          <p>Путь: img/design/gallery/livingRoom</p>
          <p>Формат: .jpg</p>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

пример [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/a1aOTIFqbKRu3Uu6GZbw?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` - это обычный проход по массиву с копированием элемента у которого установлен этот атрибут.

Так как требуется сформировать два не связанных между собой блока - потребуется два `ng-repeat`

1. один построит ссылки

   ```
   <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.category}}</a>
   ```
2. второй - списки

   ```
   <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
   </ul>
   ```
3. Так как элементы списков - сами являются массивом - нужен еще один ng-repeat по ним для построения `<li>`,

   ```
   <li ng-repeat="example in item.example></li>
   ```
4. и еще один - для прохода по конечным объекта и построения `<p>`

   ```
   <p ng-repeat="data in example">{{data}}</p>
   ```

Пример:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      "category": "Ванные комнаты",
      "example": [{
        "source": "img/design/gallery/bathRoom",
        "format": ".jpg"
      }, {
        "source": "img/design/gallery/bathRoom",
        "format": ".jpg"
      }]
    }, {
      "category": "Гостиная комнаты",
      "example": [{
        "source": "img/design/gallery/livingRoom",
        "format": ".jpg"
      }, {
        "source": "img/design/gallery/livingRoom",
        "format": ".jpg"
      }]
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.category}}</a>
  </div>

  <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li ng-repeat="example in item.example">
      <p ng-repeat="(key,val) in example">{{key}}: {{val}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```